# Run a linux command (i.e. ls) from a RoR web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, command

I had to build a RoR web application that executes linux commands, for instance on my web page I have an "ls" button, how can I make the system run the command, retrieve the output and show the output on my web page? Is there a particular gem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be able to do that simply by doing something like:

```
<pre>
     <?= `ls` ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have access to the machine from the web app due to security policies. Anyway with Ruby you can use [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/cocaine) gem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this extremely informative link: http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html. He describes the advantages / disadvantages to the various ways ruby can call shell commands, including how to pass `stdin`, capture `stderr`, etc.